# How to dynamically set the key in a reduce function

Tags: javascript

I have a .txt file with all the scrabble letter quantities in:

`A-9, B-2, C-2, D-4, E-12, F-2, G-3, H-2, I-9, J-1, K-1, L-4, M-2, N-6, O-8, P-2, Q-1, R-6, S-4, T-6, U-4, V-2, W-2, X-1, Y-2, Z-1`

I am trying to get an array of objects from this, where the key is the letter, and the value is the number.

The problem I am having is where I am trying to set the key to be the first item in the array (that I split earlier) `[A, 9]`.

The code I have is as follows. Any tips would be gratefully received :)

```
import fs from 'fs'

var output = fs.readFileSync('scrabble-quantities.txt', 'utf-8')
    .trim()
    .split(', ')
    .map(item => item.split('-'))
    .reduce((quantities, item) => {
        quantities.push({
            item[0]: item[1]
        })
        return quantities
    }, [])
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the resulting array to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an object instead of an array. It's easier and more natural how JS works:

```
// ...
.reduce((quantities, item) => {
    quantities[item[0]] = item[1];
    return quantities;
}, {});
```

The resulting `output` object is then (in JSON notation):

```
{
  "A": 9,
  "B": 2,
  // ...
  "Z": 1
}
```

**EDIT:** mind the value type

If you want the value to be an actual number you will have to parse it in the assignment with:

```
parseInt(item[1], 10)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initial value for `reduce()` be `{}` instead of `[]`?

Comment: Excellent! I missed that one :) Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the conversion of the value from a string to an integer. @pid

Comment: Thanks, I've added it as an edit because it is not really sure if he wants the value to be a number or a numeral.

Comment: Wicked - thanks again guys - parseInt is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

To create a key (property name) dynamically, you need to do one of two things:

1. In ES5 and earlier, you have to create the object and then set the property:

   ```
      var o = {};
      o[item[0]] = item[1];
   ```
2. In ES2015 (aka ES6) and later, you can use a *dynamic property name* in a property initializer via `[]`:

   ```
      // ES2015 (ES6) ONLY
      quantities.push({
          [item[0]]: item[1]
      })
   ```

---

That said, I'd come at the problem differently, using regex and ending up with an object keyed by the letter rather than an array of objects:

```js
var str = "A-9, B-2, C-2, D-4, E-12, F-2, G-3, H-2, I-9, J-1, K-1, L-4, M-2, N-6, O-8, P-2, Q-1, R-6, S-4, T-6, U-4, V-2, W-2, X-1, Y-2, Z-1";
var quantities = {};
str.match(/[A-Z]-\d/g).forEach(function(entry) {
  quantities[entry.charAt(0)] = +entry.replace(/.-/, '');
});
console.log(quantities);
```

Then, looking up the quantity of a letter becomes `quantities.A` (or `quantities[letter]` if `letter` is a variable containing `"A"`):

```
console.log(quantities.A); // 9
```

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks for the typo fix!